# Silverlight3: Returned localized string, when binding without converter, is always in "en-US" culture

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, binding, localization

The problem:
 The returned localized string for the non-string binding properties (DateTime, double...) is always set to "en-US" culture, regardless of the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
The solution I am looking for: 
I am looking for a solution other than using a converter  (The localization works properly if a converter is used), since I need to implement it in an existing large Silverlight3 application where converters were not used in the first palce.
The Question:
How to make localization work with non-string binding properties, without converters ?
thnx
Krsto

Answer (score 2):

Do the following in the constructor of your App.Xaml:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");

And then this in the constructor of every user control:
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

That might work, give it a try. Of course you will have to adjust the culture to whatever it is you want to do.